# Regular Expression to Extract Text from poorly formatted HTML block

Tags: regex, scrapy

I am web scraping a page, and I am forced to use regular expressions (something I am terrible at) to extract the information I need, because the HTML has very little structure. The HTML snippet is as follows:

```
LEEDS TOWN HALL<br>
Wednesday, 15 May 2013, 6:30PM - 8:30PM<br>
Tickets £7/£5 for including a glass of wine available in store or via 01234 567 890
```

I would like to first break the block into three parts at the html break tags, then use regular expressions to extract the information I need.

How do I split the block into three to start with?

Thanks

Comment: you don't want a regex for the whole thing. split on the `<br>` then treat each individual line separately. one monster regex that tries to do it all will just tear you one big monster hole in your behind.

Comment: Thanks Marc, makes sense. Q edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need *one* regex with 5 groups:

```
(?s)([^<]+).*?, (.*?) - (.*?)<br>(.*)
```

Since you made no attempt to create a regex, I'm making no attempt to explain mine :)

Comment: Is there a place where I can paste my source, and your regular expression, and get the output, to see if it is what I want? I tried a few that Google brought up, but can't see output !

Comment: Regexpal and regextester are two I've used

Comment: RegexTester tells me at the bottom that it got no Match ! am I missing something?